# Azure DevOps & Bower - include bower_components in build package

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, bower

I have a following pipeline on Azure DevOps

[image: Azure DevOps build pipeline]

everything works as expected however I am very confused of how to include the bower_components folder in my build package as MsBuild is not aware of the bower folder.

I am successfully able to pull down the packages to the bower_components folder however I am not aware of recommended way of how to include the folder in my final package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding this to my **.csproj** file:

```
  <Target Name="AddBowerComponents" BeforeTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage;CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy">
    <Message Text="Adding bower components" Importance="high"/>
    <ItemGroup>
      <CustomFilesToInclude Include=".\bower_components\**\*.*" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject  Include="%(CustomFilesToInclude.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>.\bower_components\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```